# TestPyPI / test.pipy.org error "This filename has already been used" caused by uploading project with the same name and version

Tags: pypi

**TLDR:** What to do with the error after deleting project from TestPyPI (test.pypi.org) and want to re-upload using the same project name and version?

**Answer:** [You cannot use the same project name and version after PyPI and TestPyPI switched to Warehouse.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56520660/upload-a-new-release-to-testpypi) Successfully uploaded to TestPyPI after bumping setup.py version from '0.0.1' to '0.0.2'

**Why new post:** Title of the above entry does not reflect the problem in detail, making it difficult to be found

---

**Description:**

I was testing a package I wrote using TestPyPI before releasing it to PyPI.
However, I discovered there are some errors when I pip install from test.pypi.org:

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ PACKAGE_NAME
```

Thinking I made mistakes during packaging and wanting to re-upload my package, I removed my package from test.pypi.org using the "Manage" button.
[image]

However, now when I try to upload my adjusted package like I used to do:

```
twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
```

I receive the "filename has already been used" error.

```
HTTPError: 400 Bad Request from https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
This filename has already been used, use a different version. See https://test.pypi.org/help/#file-name-reuse for more information.
```

I followed the [link](https://test.pypi.org/help/#file-name-reuse) and read:

```
PyPI does not allow for a filename to be reused, even once a project has been deleted and recreated.
```

So my questions are:

**1. Can I still test the package release on TestPyPI using the same filename?** (After all, I am using TestPyPI, not PyPI. Shouldn't I be allowed to reset my TestPyPI workspace to its original state? Isn't this the purpose of using TestPyPI?)

**2. Am I using TestPyPI the wrong way (in terms of how to delete a project or what TestPyPI is designed to do)?** (I was surprised my project still "exists" after I deleted it, as you can see below. I suspect this is why the filename remains occupied after I deleted the project.)

---

Figure 1: This is what is displayed after removing the project. It seems the project still exists.

[image: This is what is displayed]

Figure 2: This is what happens when you click in. It seems the project does not really exist? Project limbo!

[image: This is what happens when you click in]